# Core Data relationships issue

Tags: ios, core-data

I've got a simple app with three views `HomeViewController`, `AddViewController`, and `AddCategoryViewController`.

My data model has two Entities, with relationships like this:

[image]

My goal is to be able to display `WMDGActivity` objects in the tableview in `HomeViewController`, grouped under sections defined by `WMDGCategory` objects.

New `WMDGCategory` objects are added via a textfield in `AddCategoryViewController`and new `WMDGActivity` objects are added via a textfield in `AddViewController`.

My problem is that the app crashes upon canceling or saving in either of the auxiliary views. The error code is invariably:

```
reason: '[<WMDGActivity 0x8a54830> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity WMDGActivity is not key value coding-compliant for the key "WMDGCategory".'
```

I also see this every time I roll the picker wheel containing the names of WMDGCategory objects:

```
data: {
    activities = "<relationship fault: 0x8db1600 'activities'>";
    name = Pastimes;
```

Indeed, another mystery is that the app is apparently saving these objects before the crash. I've tried stepping through the code, but haven't come up with a solution yet. I suspect there is a problem with the way my entities are set up, or with my code that interacts with them.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code:

From HomeViewController (delegate for both `AddViewController`, and `AddCategoryViewController`:

```
#pragma mark AddViewControllerDelegate stuff

-(void) addViewControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

-(void) addViewControllerDidCancel:(WMDGActivity *) activityToDelete
{
    [activityToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

#pragma mark AddCatControllerDelegate stuff

-(void) addCatControllerDidSave
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}

-(void) addCatControllerDidCancel:(WMDGCategory *) categoryToDelete
{
    [categoryToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self refreshData];

}
```

From AddCategoryViewController:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (self.catTextField.text.length > 0)
    {
        self.thisCategory.name = self.catTextField.text;
    }
    [self.delegate addCatControllerDidSave];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.delegate addCatControllerDidCancel:self.thisCategory];
}
```

And from AddViewController:

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (self.activityField.text.length > 0)
    {

        if (self.categoryLabel.text.length < 1)
        {
            self.thisCategory.name = @"Uncategorized";
            //            self.thisActivity.activityName = self.activityField.text;
            //            [self.delegate addActivityViewControllerDidSave];
        }

        else
        {
        self.thisCategory.name = self.categoryLabel.text;
        self.thisActivity.name = self.activityField.text;
        NSLog(@"Category name is %@", self.thisCategory.name);
        NSLog(@"Activity name is %@", self.thisActivity.name);
        }


        [self.delegate addViewControllerDidSave];

    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No activity entered"
                                                        message:@"Please enter a new activity or Cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }



}

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.delegate addViewControllerDidCancel:self.thisActivity];
}
```

Can anyone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the app crashes upon canceling or saving in either of the auxiliary views. The error code is invariably:

It would help to see the error call stack and the code where the error occurred. But I'll go ahead and throw out a guess, which is that you're configuring an `NSFetchedResultsController` and specifying `WMDGCategory` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`. There are two things wrong with this. First, the key path is `toCategory`. `WMDGCategory` is the data type. Second, to organize your table view by category name, you would need to use the key path `toCategory.name`. Also, you're going to need to pre-sort your activities by `toCategory.name` (a requirement of `NSFetchedResultsController`).

> I also see this every time I roll the picker wheel containing the names of WMDGCategory objects:

What you're seeing is the description of the `WMDCategory` object. What you need is the value of the name property. You need to use `[category valueForKey:@"name"]`, or if you're using convenience classes, `category.name`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried implementing your suggestions and perhaps went too far with a couple of other changes. Now I find myself with a new issue, clearly related, but maybe far enough removed that I don't know whether to edit my original question or start a new one. Well, here's a snip of the error stack: ***data: {
    category = nil;
    name = Programming;
    toCategory = nil;***

Comment: Sorry, here's the rest of that statement:

Comment: ***}) returned nil value for section name key path 'toCategory.name'. Object will be placed in unnamed section*** Danged send-on-return!

Comment: It means either a) the activity doesn't have a value for `toCategory` or b) the category doesn't have a value for `name`. If you can't figure it out, it probably warrants a new question because you'll need to give details relevant to the problem.

Comment: I expect I just haven't yet got my head around the relationship between the data model and the implementation code for making it do it's tricks. I'm gonna sleep on it and see if the Xcode elves fix it overnight. Many thanks for responding! You'll probably be seeing me again. :)